# Symfony 2.8, sonata admin bundle form builder - request takes too long when I make simple php error

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

Example part of the code:

```
$builder
            ->add('insuredType', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => 'VopPolicyBundle:AdditionalInsuredType',
                    'empty_value' => 'Additional insured type',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'required' => true,
                    'choices' => $this->additionalInsuredTypeManager->getProductInsuredTypes()

                )
            )
```

The function getProductInsuredTypes() requires one parameter to be passed.
I found out this using xdebug.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSIhh.jpg

And nginx is timing out, even when I increased time limit to 5 minutes. Before it was also set in php.ini 128MB memory limit, but I was getting error about too small memory. I tried even 1 GB memory, then I set -1 - unlimitted. And when setting unlimited, started getting this timeout.

Why it happens so?

Comment: To be sure we got it: if you give the function getProductInsuredTypes() 1 parameter, it works. If you remove the parameter, which makes the code false, you get a timeout or a memory limit error, depending on your config. Is that right ?

Comment: yes, it it is right

Comment: An error "expects at least 1 parameters, 0 given" has probably be thrown. But it looks like in your case, something catches this error and tries to perform some long process that gets killed in the end. Do your Symfony Debug ToolBar work correctly ? Maybe it is broken. It can happen for example if it tries to call a function that is recursively called and it never ends.

Can you try this line of code `$this->additionalInsuredTypeManager->getProductInsuredTypes()` outside of this form ? Then outside of a Symfony Controller, in a Command for example ?

Comment: Looks like debug toolbar works correctly. I moved this function outside of form to a controller and then debug bar shows normal error Type error: Too few arguments to function Vop\PolicyBundle\Entity\AdditionalInsuredTypeManager::getProductInsuredTypes(), . Same when moving to command.